# Datepicker not exceeding on current date

Tags: jquery

i have a datepicker labeled for my Year Graduate. how can i limit my datepicker in exceeding on the current date. Or. how can i limit the user not to select a future date. also is there a validation that the date selected "dateTo" will be greater than "dateFrom"

here's my html code

```
<label>Year Graduated from</label>
   <input id="dateFrom" type="date">
<label>Year Graduated to</label>
       <input id="dateTo" type="date">
```

here's my jquery code

```
$( "#date_assigned" ).datepicker({
     showOtherMonths: true,
     selectOtherMonths: true,
     dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy"
     });
     });

 $(function() {
      $( "#date_returned" ).datepicker({
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy"
         });
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2tn4A/3/)

```
$(function () {
    var dateFormat = 'dd.mm.yy';

    $("#from").datepicker({
        maxDate: '0',
        dateFormat: dateFormat,
        onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
            var date = $.datepicker.parseDate(dateFormat, selectedDate)
            var tod = date.setDate(date.getDate());
            $to.prop('disabled', false).datepicker( "option", "minDate", new Date(tod ));
        }
    });
    var $to = $("#to").datepicker({
        dateFormat: dateFormat
    }).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

**Explanation**

Set `maxDate:'0'` so the no future date is selected in `from` id date-picker

Pass selected date to `to` is date-picker using `onSelect` method and set it as `minDate` option in `to` date-picker so that `to`  date is always greater than `from` date.

References

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect

Answer (score 2):

For selecting date ranges see the excellent example on the jquery ui page:

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range

You can use the `minDate` and `maxDate` options for limiting the available dates and the `onClose` event of each datepicker to refresh the min/max-date on the other datepicker to achieve a valid range selection.

Note that `minDate` and `maxDate` accept a range of different values. If the value is a number it is understood as an offset from today, i.e. a zero will be today, -1 will be yesterday and so on.